# Editing nested listview producing "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I’ve got an asp.net page with a listview on it, this master listview has several child (nested) listviews within it.

The idea of the page is that the master listview will only ever display 1 record at a time but each of the child list view could contain 0 or more records. Regardless of whether the master listview is being inserted or editing, the user should be able to insert, edit and delete rows within the child listviews

What I’m finding is that when I’m insetting a record into the master listview and editing (press the update button) on any row within any of the child listviews I’m getting this error message:

> Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: ‘JobID’ Key being
>   added: 'JobID'

when I press the update button in any of the nested listviews.

I know that this error message typical means that I’m trying to insert an item with a key that matches something else already held but while ‘JobID’ is within the child listviews it is not a primary key but it is the key of the master listview but I’m not (knowingly) doing anything with the master listview.

I’m not receiving any error messages when the master listview is being edited or then the master listview is inserting and I’m inserting rows into the child listviews

If it makes any difference all listviews have properties of a singleton object as their datasources.

What I suspect is happening is that when I press the update button in the child listview something is calling the master listview. Because the master listview is in “insert mode”, the master listview is trying to insert the master details into something resulting in a “second” inserting record.

If my suspicion is correct, does any one have any ideas how I can stop the master listview firing its insert routine? Am I missing something or is this a “feature” of listviews?

Code below

Thanks in advance

Master list view

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvJob" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsJob" 
    DataKeyNames="JobID" oniteminserting="lvJob_ItemInserting" 
    onitemupdating="lvJob_ItemUpdating"  
    onitemupdated="lvJob_ItemUpdated"  
    oniteminserted="lvJob_ItemInserted" EditIndex="0" 
    onprerender="lvJob_PreRender" ondatabound="lvJob_DataBound" >
```

Child list view

```
        <asp:ListView ID="lvQuotes" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuoteID"
            DataSourceID="dsQuotes" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" 
            oniteminserting="lvQuotes_ItemInserting" 
            oniteminserted="lvQuotes_ItemInserted" 
            onitemupdated="lvQuotes_ItemUpdated"
            OnItemUpdating="lvQuotes_ItemUpdating" >        
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                <td>
                   <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                       Text="Update" CssClass="ListButton" />
                   <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                       Text="Cancel" CssClass="ListButton" />
```

As requested - the Code behind just to note when the error occurs these events are not fired but they do fire in other scenarios

updating event on one of the child listviews

```
    protected void lvQuotes_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //meaningless code to attach a breakpoint to
        JobId = JobId;
    }
```

Inserting event on the Master list view

```
    protected void lvJob_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            e.Values["DateRecieved"] = TestDate(e.Values["DateRecieved"]);
            e.Values["DateDue"] = TestDate(e.Values["DateDue"]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            ShowErrorMsg(ex);
        }
```

Comment: You just posted mark up. Apparently you have something wrong in your code. I need to see the event handlers that are called when inserting and updating.

Comment: I haven't included the code behind because it has nothing to do with the problem. The error is occurring between clicking the update button on the the child listview and the itemupdating event firing, I should also add the the iteminserting event on the master is not firing either. That said for clarity I will edit the question to include some of the code behind.